# DirectoryInfo.Extension - Why does this exist?

Tags: .net, file-extension

I just noticed that the `DirectoryInfo` class has the `Extension` property, inherited from `FileSystemInfo`.  I am confused why this was made part of the base class instead of only being declared and implemented in the `FileInfo` class.  That is, since directories don't have extensions, this seems to be a strange design decision.

Furthermore, I was just working with a `DirectoryInfo` instance and noticed the `Extension` property seemed rather arbitrary.  It appeared to be the original name of the folder (not the current name), converted to lower case.  For example, let's say I had a folder that was originally name *MyCoolFolder*.  Later, I changed the name to *MyGoodFolder*.  The `DirectoryInfo.Extension` property would, supposably, based on what I've seen, read **.mycoolfolder**.  Why?  What could be useful about having the `Extension` property on a `DirectoryInfo`, and what's useful about having the original name in lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be valid to have a directory with an "extension". It is allowed both in the filesystem and .NET. In that context, I suppose the `Extension` property is behaving correctly. That said, I've never seen a directory with an extension, other than "hidden" directories that start with a period (.git, .vs, etc).

Example:

```
var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\temp.txt");
Console.WriteLine(dir.Exists); //True
Console.WriteLine(dir.Extension); //.txt
```

Also, I should point out the behavior the OP supposes about how `Extension` works is incorrect (not sure why they didn't just test...) `Extension` looks for a period and returns the period and everything after it. For a directory name without a period Extension will return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a design flaw of this object hierarchy.

If you think this is bad look at (only left relevant code):

```
public abstract class Array : IList
{
  int IList.Add(object value)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_FixedSizeCollection"));
  }
}
```

Just accept that .net framework designers make mistakes too and that mistake made in widely used API is very hard if not impossible to fix as backwards compatibility most often has higher priority.

Comment: I thought it might just be a flaw, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't some secret world of directory extensions I didn't know about. I like your additional example, though it seems more philosophical. That is, not everyone has always agreed that NotSupportedException is a bad idea (they did provide that exception, after all), whereas I don't think anyone could make a case for directories needing extensions. It seems more like a mere technical oversight.

Comment: No, I don't have doubts. I agree it makes a poor API because you can't substitute Arrays for other ILists that support Add(), and it could've been avoided with a different approach. Declaring Extension in FileSystemInfo when it's only needed by one derived class just seems like a clerical error. Maybe they planned on having more than 2 derived classes? The behavior implemented in DirectoryInfo makes it even more odd. The original name, to lower, with a dot at the beginning? Strange.

Comment: I don't see a problem with having the prop `Extension` in the DirectoryInfo class since they can contain `.`